# Are there any other iOS system sounds available other than 'tock'?

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I have implemented an alternative keyboard on my first iPhone app. I would like to play a sound when a button is pressed. The default click sound when the standard keyboard is pressed would be fine, but I don't know how to get that sound.

In this answer I found how to play a 'tock' sound:

[Playing system sound without importing your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831671/playing-system-sound-without-importing-your-own)

I got this to work easily enough but it is a very loud sound. I've searched Stack Overflow and the Xcode help for available iOS system sounds other than 'tock' and I can't find them.

Are there other built-in sounds, maybe even the default keyboard sound, that I can use?

Comment: If the question would really be what its title suggests, I,d dare answering 'there's AVSystemSoundID_Vibrate'.

Answer (score 18):

Prior to, and since posting this question almost 2 weeks ago I have searched high and low for a method to make the keyboard click sound work in my app. I have attempted to implement and understand [Apple's documentation on custom input views.](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW4) I butchered my app in many ways attempting to make it work and created several test projects. I tried to interpret how to do this from various other sources on the web. All to no avail. I have finished my app all but for this last function.

I finally hit on a simple answer towards the end of [this IPhone Dev SDK form question/post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140823194156/http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/103267-uiinputviewaudiofeedback-not-working.html).  The ultimate answer is easy and can be done in a few seconds with these easy steps.

1. **Link the 'AudioToolbox.framework' to your project** (Click on your project's Target, select 'Build Phases' and under the 'Link Binary with Libraries' item click the + button and add the framework.
2. Add the following to the header file of the class where you want to implement the click:

   ```
    #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
   ```
3. Add the following line of code in the implementation file of your class wherever you want the keyboard click sound to appear:

   ```
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(0x450);
   ```

THAT'S IT! AND IT WORKED!!! HALLELUJAH!

According to Paul in the other forum this has the following downside:

"keyboard keys won't be affected by the iOS user preference for keyboard sound on/off."

But when I turn the volume up or down on my iPhone or if I mute the iPhone, the keyboard click sounds do go up and down or are muted as would be expected. Given that I found it impossible to implement keyboard clicks "UIInputViewAudioFeedback" as documented, I'm happy to have anything work.

P.S. If anyone has a link to an actual project that I can download, build and run on my iPhone to see EXACTLY how to properly implement: "UIInputViewAudioFeedback" I'd be happy to give it a look. But so far I've found none, nor any step-by-step newbie style instructions on how to make it work.

**[Sept 30, 2012 UPDATE:]** I'm happy to say that my app was accepted into the app store using this method. Here it is: https://itunes.apple.com/app/fine-tip-tip-calculator/id563429225

...Dale

Comment: I had given up on finding a solution for this. Thank you for posting.

Comment: Here is a link with all the sound codes you can input into the method. http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices

Comment: @Dale Dietrich I am sorry,I followed every step of yours,but still couldn't play any sound for button click

Comment: Works great for input events, but it sounds awful for wheels, like the datepicker, the sounds overlay each other, thanks anyway!

Comment: Is there really no constant that can be used in place of `0x450` ?!

Comment: Thanks, Dale.  One thing I noticed on iOS 8.1.3/iPhone 6 is that I was able to play:         AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1114); //  = "endrecord.caf" while the video camera was on.   I was unable to get it to play via the various other sound-playback methods. 
Also NOTE:  most sounds in the iphondevwiki (link in above comment) would not play in that scenario.

Comment: Check out this answer. Maybe it is useful to you playing sounds without using the audiotoolbox: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39385287/1306012

Answer (score 7):

Try `UIDevice`'s [`playInputClick`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDevice/playInputClick):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
```

From the documentation:

> Use this method to play the standard system keyboard click in response to a user tapping in a custom input or keyboard accessory view. A click plays only if the user has enabled keyboard clicks in Settings > Sounds, and only if the input view is itself enabled and visible.

Make sure you adopt the `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` protocol in your input view class, and implement the `enableInputClicksWhenVisible` delegate method to return `YES`, as per the documentation.

**EDIT** - For implementation of delegate methods, check out [Apple's documentation on custom input views](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW1).

Comment: Thanks mopsled! 

I'm a bit over my head. I can't get this to work. Here's what I've done so far.

In my view *.h file I added **bolded text**:

'@interface TipMainViewController : UIViewController <TipFlipsideViewControllerDelegate,  **UIInputViewAudioFeedback**>'

'@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL enableInputClicksWhenVisible;' 

In my view *.m file I added:

'@synthesize enableInputClicksWhenVisible;'

'- (BOOL) enableInputClicksWhenVisible { return YES; }'

and inserted the following where I wanted the tick sound:

'[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];'

What did I do wrong?

Comment: SORRY, I tried and tried to format the above with some structure but the commenting system  here doesn't seem to permit it. :(

Comment: Your implementation is close, but you shouldn't be adding any `@property` or `@synthesize` statements to implement a delegate. Also, you should be implementing the protocol on the input view, not the view controller. Check out the link I added to my answer above.

Comment: OK, but I do not have a separate keyboard input view. I am using a TextField that I dragged onto the view controller's xib file. I hide the normal keyboard and implement a keyboard through buttons that I also added on to the view controller's xib file.  I did read the excellent tutorial you linked to in the "EDIT" field above. Thinking I was following its instructions I went down the road of creating a separate UITextField Class called 'KeyboardClick'. Using the Identity Inspector in Interface builder I linked the applicable input Text Field to the new KeyboardClick Class. [OUT OF SPACE :(]

Comment: I must confess that I don't fully understand protocols and delegation. Do I need to instantiate the new KeybardClick class? I tried doing this but nothing happened. Plus xCode said it was an unused variable. I'm getting discouraged.