# Need to access the default camera shutter sound used by the iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-5, iphone-4, audiotoolbox

Right now when a user presses a button I play a custom camera shutter sound.

However, if possible, I would much rather just use the camera shutter sound that plays by default whenever you take a photo using your iPhone.

Is there a way that I can access and use the default iPhone camera shutter sound? And if yes, then where is it actually located?

I need to figure out it's file path so that I can use it with the code below and just change the input for `pathForResource`:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shutter" ofType: @"wav"];

    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath ];

    self.myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

    [self.myAudioPlayer play];
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1108);
```

Based on:
[Are there any other iOS system sounds available other than 'tock'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255164/are-there-any-other-ios-system-sounds-available-other-than-tock)
and
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices

For 2016 ....

```
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(SystemSoundID(1108), nil)
    } else {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1108)
    }
```

Comment: From iOS9, `AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion` is preferred - the header comments for `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` indicate it will be deprecated.

Comment: Note that you need to import AVKit to get access to these methods

Answer (score 6):

Looking at stevesliva's answer helped me greatly. However, I ended up with this:

```
Unexpected type name 'SystemSoundID': expected expression
```

... using this line...

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(SystemSoundID(1108), nil);
```

So, using this lump of code got my App playing the camera-shutter noise:

```
SystemSoundID soundID = 1108;

AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(soundID, ^{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: That's because the code you quoted is Swift. Did you even look at the ObjC/C API?
It should be `AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion((SystemSoundID)1108, nil);`

Comment: The OP question is in Obj-C. The accepted answer is in Swift - I thought this odd. I added my comment hoping my actual Obj-C response would help someone.

Comment: The answer is in Obj C, and has been edited with Swift.