# How to make sound when notification came if application is active in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MessageReceived" object:self];

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {

//        NSString *cancelTitle = @"Close";
        NSString *showTitle = @"Show";
//        NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Order"
                                                            message:@"You just received new order"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                     otherButtonTitles:showTitle, nil];

        UILocalNotification *localNotifcation = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotifcation.userInfo = userInfo;
        localNotifcation.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
//        localNotifcation.alertBody = message;
        localNotifcation.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotifcation];

        [alertView show];

    }
    else {
        //Do stuff that you would do if the application was not active
    }
}
```

Please give me a solution how can i get sound when application is running if notification came right now am using x-code 6.3?

Comment: you can use AVAudioPlayer with custom ringtone to play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following framework

```
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

Use below code -

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {

        SystemSoundID soundID;
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef ref = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef)@"mySoundName.wav", NULL, NULL);
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(ref, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
    else {
        // Push Notification received in the background
    }
}
```

**Or** You may used system sound -

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1007);
```

For Vibration -

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

See [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices) all list of sound.

Comment: that mySoundName.wav file i have to add to the project ?

Comment: Yes , Otherwise you may play directly system using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1007); Please see my above post for sound code

Comment: AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1007);

Comment: Is there any possible to change title of notification ?

Comment: No ,I think its not possible , its always show your name as title.

Comment: Shouldn't ref been released with CFRelease(ref) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually add sound file and play it when app is active.

```
if ([application applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        NSLog(@"active");

      NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alarm2" ofType:@"wav"];
        NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL, &_mySound);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.mySound);
    }
```

For more default sounds check this answer : [Playing system sound without importing your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7831768/3202193)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

try this code. put this code for `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in `AppDelegate`.m

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef ref = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef)@"Voicemail.wav", NULL, NULL);
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(ref, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

this code perfect work for me..

Comment: Is there any possible to change title of notification ?

Comment: Not possible. Please Read This documents. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html