# iOS Swift camera mode- how to indicate photo is captured

Tags: ios, swift, camera, photo, capture

In Camera mode (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) I manage to capture a photo successfully. I would like to indicate this fact to the user- meaning to show him a sudden black flash and a click sound- similar to what he would experience when taking a photo himself.

How do I do that? Is there some built in functionality that does that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to do this, but it's pretty simple to do on your own by adding a black UIView with alpha set to zero in your camera view hierarchy, then playing system sound and animating the "flash" view's alpha when the photo is captured.

In `viewDidLoad`, `loadView`, or wherever you assemble your view hierarchy

```
// Assuming cameraView contains your previewLayer...
flashView = UIView(frame: <set your frame>)
flashView.alpha = 0
flashView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
cameraView.addSubview(flashView)
```

Then, in your capture completion block

```
// Animate the "flash"
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: 0, options: .Autoreverse, animations: { () -> Void in
    flashView.alpha = 1
}, completion: nil)

// Play the camera shutter system sound
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1108)
```

For more info on the system sounds, see this question: [Playing system sound without importing your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831671/playing-system-sound-without-importing-your-own).

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why the .Autoreverse didn't work for me but I just added another closure in the completion variable that returns the alpha value to zero

Comment: That's odd -- maybe it was too short to see, or maybe too many things going on at once? Glad you were able to work around it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 4:

```
@IBOutlet weak var lightView: UIView! //First set lightView hidden in the storyboard

    //MARK: - Take Screenshot Animation
    func flashAnimation(image: UIImage, rect: CGRect) {
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: lightView)
        lightView.alpha = 0
        lightView.isHidden = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.lightView.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
            self.hideFlashView()
        })
    }

    func hideFlashView() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, animations: {() -> Void in
            self.lightView.alpha = 0.0
        })
    }
```