# Play system ringtones using iOS CallKit

Tags: ios, callkit

I can use ringtones built into my app for incoming calls with CallKit by calling

```
let configuration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedname:"MyApp")
configuration.ringtoneSound = "mysound.wav"
```

However, I want to use system ringtones, like the "Beacon" ringtone which is stored at "/Library/Ringtones/Beacon.m4r". Setting configuration.ringtoneSound to "/Library/Ringtones/Beacon.m4r", "Ringtones/Beacon.m4r", "Beacon.m4r" all don't work.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the system ringtones, and how to use them?

To repeat: The problem is not playing the ringtones, that's easy. The problem is making CallKit use the system ringtones for an incoming call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playing system sound without importing your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831671/playing-system-sound-without-importing-your-own)

Comment: No. I have code that plays system ringtones. What I don't have is code that plays system ringtones through CallKit, when a VoIP call comes in and I have to show the CallKit user interface.

Comment: @gnasher729 Did you find any solution yet? If you did please share so that we can get the right solution. Thank you